# Running Valgrind in the background

Tags: valgrind

I am trying to run Valgrind on a daemon over several days via ssh connection.
In order to run it in the background I am using the following command:

```
nohup valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --error-limit=no --log-file=/var/log/valgrind_log.txt hello_world </dev/null >/dev/null &
```

However when disconnecting from ssh, Valgrind seems to stop.

Does someone know if it is possible to run Valgrind for several days, in the background, and that it will keep running after closing the ssh connection? If so, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Isn't the '&' a guest argument rather than a Valgrind one? Try putting parens around the command like `nohup (valgrind ./guest) &`. Or else try running in the foreground and then putting it in the background e,g,, with ctrl-z and `bg`. [I haven't tried either of them]

Comment: @PaulFloyd I have tried adding the    'valgrind .... >/dev/null' into a script named 
    'script.sh' and then running    'nohup ./script.sh &', without success

Comment: I just tried nohup valgrind --log-file=s.out sleep 1000 < /dev/null > /dev/null &
and it all continues to work when disconnecting from ssh: when ssh again, valgrind is still running.  What do you mean by 'stop' ? Does it crash ? Or does it not progress anymore ? Try to use strace on valgrind to see what it does if it is not crashed. If it crashes, use -v -v -v -d -d -d (and keep the output) to see what is going on

Comment: @phd thank you for verifying the problem is with me. The process is somehow killed - if I watch `ps aux` on the pid, I can see it becoming `[memcheck-x86-li] <defunct>` for a moment and disappearing from the process list. Maybe I am a little confused about how it should work. sigtrace of pid 21898 shows `SIGCHLD si_code=CLD_EXITED si_pid=21987` and then `process detached` (I'm not sure if SIGCHLD is related)

Comment: Is it working for you with sleep ? What is -v -v -v -v -d -d -d -d producing as trace ?